Linear programming formulation of maximizing number of nonzero components
I want to turn the following problem into a linear programming problem, thus it can be solved efficiently: find $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $Ax=b$ ($A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n},b\in\mathbb{R}^m$) and $x\geq 0$, such that the number of non-zero components of $x$ is maximized.
I know how to solve when $b=0$. You can introduce $y,z\geq0$ and require $y_i\leq 1$, let $x=y+z$, then maximize $\sum_i^n y_i$. Any thought on how to generalize this method into the case where $b\neq 0$ is greatly appreciated.

it's interesting but I don't quite follow. Suppose one just maximizes $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}$ directly.  Then, clearly, the sum is not the same as the number of non-zero components of $x$ so that won't work. But I don't see why your way works even in the case of $b=0$. Thanks for un-confusing me.

I think I'm missing on the use of $z$.  Is it added in to $x$ so that the maximization of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i}$ ( which is similar to maximizing $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} $) doesn't negatively interact with the $Ax =b$ constraint ? The dimension of the solution space kind of remains the same by the use of $z$ ? Is that the idea

I think I get it. By maximizing $\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i}$, you will force the $y_{i}$  to hit their upper bound of 1 when possible ( $x$ is defined to be atleast as large as $y$ ). When this is possible for some $i$, then $x_{i}$ is a non-zero component of $x$ because $y_{i}$ would not hit the upper bound if $x_{i}$ could not be non-zero because $x = y + z$ with $z \ge 0$. Therefore, by maximizing $\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i}$, the number of non-zero components of $x$ is maximized. Is that correct ?

Not necessarily efficient, but we can implement this as a MIP (Mixed-Integer Programming) problem. MIPs allow counting.
$$\begin{aligned}
   \max & \sum_i \delta_i \\
        & Ax=b \\
        & x_i \ge 0.001\cdot\delta_i \\
        & x_i \ge 0 & \text{optional bound} \\
        & \delta_i \in \{0,1\}   
\end{aligned}$$
Here, $\delta_i \in \{0,1\}$ is a binary variable.

You can do that with $n$ linear programming problems:
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
  \max_x & x_i \\
  s.t.   & Ax = b \ and \ x \geq 0
\end{array}
$$
If the maximum is 0, then any solution must have $x_i = 0$. The maximum number of non-zero components in a solution is then $n$ minus the number of components that must be 0. Denoting by $x^i$ a solution to the above problems, taking
$$
  x = \frac{\sum_i x^i}{n}
$$
gives a solution to your problem.

A practical improvement is to first maximize $\sum_i x_i$.  Then you can skip the LPs for the variables that were positive in the first solve.  In fact, you can iterate this idea.  If $x^$ maximizes $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, your second LP can be to maximize $\sum_{i: x_i^ = 0} x_i$.  Stop iterating when you get an optimal objective value of $0$.  The worst case is still $n$ solves, but the hope is that more than one $x_i>0$ at once.

Your solution when $b$ is zero is not valid, for example, if the only constraint is $x_1+x_2\leq 1$, then you can find $x_1 = y_1=1$ and $x_2=y_2=0$, but $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be made simultaneously non-zero by setting $x_1=x_2 =\frac{1}{2}$. Your trick will work if your variables are required to be integer, but then it is not a LP but an ILP.
You can't formulate this as a true LP, since it is NP-complete to minimize the number of non-zero variables but you can formulate it as a MILP, see @ErwinKalvelagen answer. However, you can compute a solution maximizing the number of non-zero variables in polynomial time.
Solve the LP optimally and add a constraint to fix the value of the objective function. You are now reduced to finding a valid solution maximizing the number of non-zero variables. From a valid solution, find the zero variables that can be augmented along valid direction. By convexity, all these variables can be made non-zero simultaneously.
